# Find hashtags with in specified part of website

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract all (in this example two) hast-tags from a web-page.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="predefinition">
            <p class="part1">
              <span class="part1-head">Entries:</span>
                <a class="pr" href="/go_somewhere/">#hashA with space</a>, 
                <a class="pr" href="/go_somewhere/">#hashBwithoutsace</a>,
            </p>
            <span class="part2">Boundaries:</span>
            <p>some boundary statement</p>
        </div>        
        <div class="wrapper"> <!– I only want to search here–>
            <p class="part1">
              <span class="part1-head">Entries:</span>
                <a class="pr" href="/go_somewhere/">#hash1 with space</a>, <!– I only want to find this–>
                <a class="pr" href="/go_somewhere/">#hash2withoutsace</a>, <!– and this–>
            </p>
            <span class="part2">Boundaries:</span>
            <p>some other boundary statement</p>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am only interested in the hash-tags in one branch (in this example wrapper): "#hash1 with space" and "#hash2withoutsace". Right now my code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import io
import re

f = io.open("minimal.html", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
contents = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
mydivs = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "pr"})

for div in mydivs:
    print(re.findall(r'(?i)\#\w+', str(div)))
```

- How do I focus my search on the "wrapper" div?
- And how to I include hashtags with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the text of all the `a` tags with `class` `pr`, and then select the last two:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
results = [i.text for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'wrapper'}).find_all('a', {'class':'pr'})]
```

Output:

```
['#hash1 with space', '#hash2withoutsace']
```

Comment: ok, you got me :-) The problem is I don't know how many tags are given to "wrapper" and "predefinition". So is it possible to focus the find_all on the "wrapper" part of the html?